# jQuery ajax POST return error in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I using this code

```
function testfunction(ttl){

        jQuery.ajax({url:"index.php",
           type: "POST",
                   cache : false,
           data: { 'data1': ttl},
           success:function(res){

                  //Do something

         },error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) { 
                   console.log(error);

        }});
    }
```

I got a error = 'error' and errorThrown = ""

This issue is only in Google chrome.

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: check request info on Network tab of Debug Tools

Comment: i mean Developer Tools

Comment: Could you post the "error"?

Comment: Have you tried the built in Network debugger in Chrome - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/chrome-dev-tools-networking-and-the-console/

Comment: @Leonardo Did you miss *"error = 'error' and errorThrown = """*

Comment: `View > Developer > Developer Tools`, select the "Network" tab and then make your request. It will let you see the request/response to/from the server, or any Javascript errors that occur.

Comment: How you trigger the testfunction(ttl) ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me - might be problem with parameter ttl which you send via ajax call

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function() {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "index2.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { 'data1': $(this).attr('rel')},
                    success: function (res) {

                        console.log(res);

                    },
                    error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(error);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button rel="test">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and index2.php

```
<?php
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: i echo json_encode($_POST); and got  {"data1":"1823"} as the result

Comment: So then if you use mine code you shoudl get json object under "res" variable name - the one in success section.